# how to create Meteor package

Tags: meteor

I read documentation about packaging https://atmosphere.meteor.com/wtf/package . And also watch the video https://eventedmind.com/feed/G6K5WCcxpt534yYrw .According to those I made package.js and smart.json file in package folder. Now my main problem is how to turn this simple example code below to reusable package ?

```
Meteor.methods({
    Tweets: function (key,url,method) {
    var key = key;
    var response = Meteor.http.call( method, url,
             { params: { appkey: key ,uid: "something" }});
    return response.content;
       }
    });
```

Here is my package.js file :

```
Package.describe({
    summary: "bla bla"
});

Package.on_use(function (api){
api.use(["http"],["server"]);

api.add_files("script.js","server");
});
```

and smart.json file:

```
    {

        "name": "Pacage name",
        "description": "description etc",
        "homepage":"http://example.com" ,
        "author" : "myname",
        "version" : "0.1",
        "packages": {}
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to create Meteorite package.

1. First, you have to create Git repository e.g. on http://github.com
2. Add git attribute in `smart.json` file with the link to the repository:
   `{ git: "https://github.com/yourlogin/repo.git" }`
3. Now, you have to register on atmosphere.meteor.com -> `Sign in` > `Create account`
4. In terminal go to the package directory and write `mrt release .`

Should work

Comment: You'll also need to create `tag` with a version number corresponding to what you have in your `smart.json` file. So in your case do something like `git tag v0.1` before callung any **meteorite** routine.

Comment: @apendua no he does not have to do it. `mrt release` will do it for him automatically. He will only have to login to github after that.